# Scrape Google Maps destinations

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to make a code for scraping Google Maps destinations. I can access destinations by using `https://www.google.com/maps/dir///`.

Then I need to input information to FROM and TO fields, select TRAVEL MODE and click SEARCH. `WebBrowser1` is embedded to Userform `DistanceSite`. Can't figure out how to click Driving button on Google Maps.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

'On Error Resume Next

   With DistanceSite.WebBrowser1

        While .ReadyState <> 4
          DoEvents
        Wend

        With .Document

            .querySelector("div.gstl_50 .sbib_b [class=tactile-searchbox-input]").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("BY17").Value

            .querySelector("div.gstl_51 .sbib_b [class=tactile-searchbox-input]").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("BY18").Value

            .querySelector("div.widget-directions-travel-mode-switcher-container [class=directions-travel-mode-icon directions-drive-icon]").Click

        End With

        End With

    'If Err <> 0 Then

       'MsgBox "There was an error running the code. Check your Internet connection. Please try one more time!"
       'Else

    'End If

    'On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class selector is incorrect for selecting the child. I guess, without looking, you have missed 1 or more of the compound classes. In this case it is sufficient to use a single class (if you choose the right one) from the compound class, in combination with parent:

```
.widget-directions-travel-mode-switcher-container .directions-drive-icon
```

You could also use an attribute = value selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Driving]").click
```

The ids may be dynamic which is why I have used the placeholder attributes in example below. Tested on UK set-up.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClickButton()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[placeholder='Choose starting point, or click on the map...']").Value = "Aylesbury"
            .querySelector("[placeholder='Choose destination...']").Value = "Brentford"
            .querySelector("[aria-label=Driving]").Click
        End With

        Stop '<delete me later

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```